# Proving by induction on the number of vertices that: every acyclic simple graph is bipartite

Tags: graph-theory, induction, bipartite-graphs

> Prove that every acyclic simple graph is bipartite, by the use of induction.

I have quite some trouble with induction. Specifically, I know that acyclic graphs have at least one vertex that has a degree of one or lower (leaf if I can recall correctly) and that if you remove that vertex you will get a cyclic graph(?), but I have trouble proving this with induction somehow, I do not know where to start.

Comment: Maybe you've had trouble, but it would still be helpful to know what you've tried. For example, what properties of acyclic graphs have you tried to apply? What does being bipartite mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Prove first the following Lemma:

Lemma: If $G$ is a graph where every vertex has degree at least 2, then $G$ contains a cycle.

This Lemma implies that your graph has a vertex of degree at most 1. Erase this vertex for the inductive step.

Comment: Yes, I understand that acyclic graphs have a vertex like that, sorry for not mentioning this in my question. What I find really difficult is connecting this fact to the bi-partiteness, and writing the mathematical induction. I've searched for some clues, but my brain is really struggling with these kind of questions somehow..

Comment: @y.m.k Erase that vertex. What does P(n) tell you?